# Rust String vs &str iterators

Tags: rust, iterator, traits

I'm trying to write a function which accepts a list of tokens. But I'm having problems making it general enough to handle two pretty similar calls:

```
let s = String::from("-abc -d --echo");

parse( s.split_ascii_whitespace() );
parse( std::env::args() );
```

- [`String::split_ascii_whitespace()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.SplitAsciiWhitespace.html#impl-Iterator) returns `std::str:SplitAsciiWhitespace` which implements `Iterator<Item=&'a str>`.
- [`std::env::args()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/struct.Args.html#impl-Iterator) returns `std::env::Args` which implements `Iterator<Item=String>`.

Is there a way for me to write a function signature for `parse` that will accept both methods?

My solution right now requires duplicating function bodies:

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("-abc -d --echo");

    parse_args( s.split_ascii_whitespace() );
    parse_env( std::env::args() );
}

fn parse_env<I: Iterator<Item=String>>(mut it: I) {
    loop {
        match it.next() {
            None => return,
            Some(s) => println!("{}",s),
        }
    }
}

fn parse_args<'a, I: Iterator<Item=&'a str>>(mut it: I) {
    loop {
        match it.next() {
            None => return,
            Some(s) => println!("{}",s),
        }
    }
}
```

If not possible, then some advice on how to use the traits so the functions can use the same name would be nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can require the item type to be `AsRef<str>`, which will include both `&str` and `String`:

```
fn parse<I>(mut it: I)
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: AsRef<str>,
{
    loop {
        match it.next() {
            None => return,
            Some(s) => println!("{}", s.as_ref()),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you like impl trait in argument position (it's a matter of taste), you can also write the signature as `fn parse(mut it: impl Iterator<Item = impl AsRef<str>>)`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, you could try:

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("-abc -d --echo");

    parse( s.split_ascii_whitespace() );
    parse( std::env::args() );
}

fn parse<T: std::borrow::Borrow<str>, I: Iterator<Item=T>>(mut it: I) {
    loop {
        match it.next() {
            None => return,
            Some(s) => println!("{}",s.borrow()),
        }
    }
}
```

I used `Borrow` as a means to get to a `&str`, but your concrete use case may be served by other, possibly custom, traits.

Comment: `Borrow` and `AsRef` are confusingly similar. Historically, the reason for the introduction of `Borrow` was that hash maps required consistency between the `Hash`, `Eq` and `Ord` implementations of the borrowed value and the original value. Since `AsRef` did not have these additional requirements, a new trait was needed. In this use case the additional requirements are irrelevant, though – we just want to convert whatever item type we get to an `&str`, so I believe `AsRef` is more appropriate here, but I'll admit that the difference is rather philosophical in this particular case.

Comment: @SvenMarnach To add to what you wrote, `AsRef<T>` is a well-known idiom with many uses in the stdlib and elsewhere. For example `AsRef<Path>` is used to [accept paths](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.open) in the many ways they can be created (from strings, `OsStr`, `PathBuf`, etc.), `AsRef<OsStr>` for things where an OS string is needed such as [command line](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.arg), and so on. `AsRef<str>` will be familiar to anyone who encountered those, while `Borrow<str>` will falsely indicate additional requirements.